# CoreData and unlimited textfields

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I'm using Swift and I need your help.

How can I save the relevant properties / parameters to CoreData when I can't set up the attributes.

In my app users can make unlimited number of textfields and I need to save that to CoreData. How can I do this? I'm a bit new to the CoreData and I'd like some help. Any tips? I know I need to set up attributes but if the user can make an unlimited number of textfields and can save that how can I do this with CoreData? Thank you for your kind help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is done by creating a model for your fields... You then give the object in question a ToMany relationship.

```
Fruit
 - name (string)
 - avg_weight (number)
 - characteristics (characteristic with to many relation)

Characteristic
  - name (string)
  - value (string)
```

You can then use a category to provide getters/setters on Fruit...

```
Fruit (CharacteristicAdditions)
 - generalShape (string) // lookup characteristics where name == 'general_shape' and return value
```

The value in this is you can then use predicates to lookup characteristics to do something like lookup all fruits whose 'general_shape' is 'round'.

There is always the secondary choice of encoding as JSON or any other serialization format... Thus:

```
Fruit
 - name (string)
 - avg_weight (number)
 - characteristics (string, json object, name as key, value as value)
```

You'd still need a category to access that encoded characteristics field in a 'clean' manner.

Comment: Thank you vary much. I think I need to go restudy CoreData cuz I still can't understand. I can't imagine how to create random number of textfields and store them and reshow them. But I think now I have a place to look :)

Comment: In that case, youd simply use my first option... not setup a category and just loop the ToMany Characteristic's to display/edit.